# check when PDO Fetch select statement returns null

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code:

```
  $check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM BetaTesterList WHERE EMAIL = ?");
                $check->execute(array($email));
                $res = $check->fetchAll();

                if (!($res['EMAIL'])){
                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO BetaTesterList(EMAIL) VALUES (?)");
                        $stmt->execute(array($email));
                } else {
                        $return['message'] = 'exists';
                }
```

However this still inserts the value although the record already exists in the DB. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things here...

1. `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` returns an array of arrays. To check for a record, try

   ```
   if (count($res) == 0) {
       // no records found
   }
   ```
2. Turn on `E_NOTICE` errors. You would have known that `$res['EMAIL']` was an undefined index. At the top of your script...

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```
3. I'd recommend creating a unique constraint on your `EMAIL` column. That way, you would not be able to insert a duplicate record. If one was attempted, PDO would trigger an error or throw an exception, depending on how you configure the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` attribute (see http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

   If you're not inclined to do so, consider using this query instead...

   ```
   $check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BetaTesterList WHERE EMAIL = ?");
   $check->execute(array($email));
   $count = $check->fetchColumn();

   if ($count == 0) {
       // no records found
   } else {
       // record exists
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

$res should look something like this:

```
array (
    [0] => array (
        [column1] => value,
        [email] => value
    ),
    [1] => array (
        [column1] => value,
        [email] => value
    ),
    [2] => array (
        [column1] => value,
        [email] => value
    )
)
```

Therefore, `if(!($res['email'))` will always evaluate to true because `$res['email']` is undefined (null, I suppose) and it is negated. So, negation of a negation = true :).